# Appending to / redefining a function?

Tags: javascript, function, redefine

I have a function `handler`:

```
function handler(data) {
    console.log(`1. ${data}`);
}
```

which I want to append, or redefine, in the same scope as follows:

```
let oldHandler = handler;
function handler(data) {
    oldHandler(data);
    console.log(`2. ${data}`);
}
```

such that when I now call `handler`:

```
handler("bar");
```

I expect the output to be:

```
1. bar
2. bar
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Currently the above results in **error: unknown: Identifier 'handler' has already been declared**.

Comment: Because of hoisting `oldHandler` will reference the second declaration of `handler` and you'll end up with infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function **declarations**:

- Declare a variable with a matching name
- Are hoisted

Use a function **expression** instead. These do neither of the above.

```js
function handler(data) {
  console.log(`1. ${data}`);
}

let oldHandler = handler;

handler = function handler(data) {
  oldHandler(data);
  console.log(`2. ${data}`);
};

handler("bar");
```